# Detect type of Display Device (Monitor/Projector) through Silverlight Client

Tags: silverlight, screen-resolution

I know that we can find the screen resolution of the client's monitor.

Is it possible to find out whether the type of device is Monitor or Projector?

If I want my web-based silverlight client to work only in Monitors and not on Projectors or vice versa, is it possible to enforce that?

The following SO question deals a similar matter in the case of java applets.
[Detect Display Type (Projector) from within the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073592/detect-display-type-projector-from-within-the-browser)

So whats the case with silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think even Windows knows that. Most of the time it's the display driver and only on laptops. So, I don't know of any easy way of doing that. You could use encrypted DRM to enforce HDCP but even then...no go more than likely. Silverlight is basically VB .net or C# so perhaps try to find an example in those languages.

EDIT: I did some more looking around and found no real API that provided a way to detect an outputs type (Monitor or Projector)